# How to solve "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute query; SQL"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I try to get all items from table Temperature by a given city id. Something went wrong and I receive the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
> execute query; SQL [select temperatur0_.id as id1_3_,
> temperatur0_.Id as Id1_3_, temperatur0_.dateTime as dateTime2_3_,
> temperatur0_.TemperatureValue as Temperat3_3_ from temperature
> temperatur0_ left outer join city_attributes city1_ on
> temperatur0_.Id=city1_.Id where city1_.Id=?]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query

I am new to java and I don't know if I used in a correct way the mapping for table relationships.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "city_attributes")
public class City {
    
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "City")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "Country")
    private String country;
    
    @Column(name = "Latitude")
    private String latitude;
    
    @Column(name = "Longitude")
    private String longitude;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private Collection<Temperature> temperatures = new LinkedList<Temperature>();
    
    public City() {}
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City [Id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", country=" + country + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude="
                + longitude + "]";
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<Temperature> getTemperatures() {
        return temperatures;
    }

    public void setTemperatures(Collection<Temperature> temperatures) {
        this.temperatures = temperatures;
    }
    
    
}
```

And

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "temperature")
public class Temperature {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateTime;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    private City city;
    
    @Column(name = "TemperatureValue")
    private double temperatureValue; 
    
    public Temperature() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public double getTemperatureValue() {
        return temperatureValue;
    }

    public void setTemperatureValue(double temperatureValue) {
        this.temperatureValue = temperatureValue;
    }
}
```

```java
try {
    city = cityService.findCityByName(name);
    Long cityId = city.getId();

    temperature = temperatureService.findTempByCityId(cityId); 
    map.addObject("temperature", temperature);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

## ===
Updated

I found this error when I debug the method from controller

> java.sql.SQLDataException: Cannot determine value type from string
> '1/1/2015 0:00'

@Robert Niestroj here is my implementation for TemperatureService and TemperatureRepository

```java
@Override
public List<Temperature> findTempByCityId(Long id) {
    return temperatureRepository.findByCityId(id);
}
```

```java
public List<Temperature> findByCityId(Long id);
```

Comment: Could you add your application code? At least the part where you are building your query.

Comment: your JoinColumn looks wrong to me. It should like @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", nullable = false)

Comment: We need to see the implementation of `temperatureService.findTempByCityId(cityId);` - the query

Comment: In your Temperature class, try to map the collumn of your dateTime attribute. Try to remove this @Temporal annotation, and change "Date" to "LocalDateTime" type

Comment: Murilo Góes de Almeida, i tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Temperature` the `@JoinColumn(name = "Id", nullable = false)` looks suspicios as it's mapped to the id column. I suspect it schould be `id_city` or sth like that. That might cause the error.

Comment: I tried your solution and that add a new column 'city_id'. I already have a column called CityId.